# Jenkins Build Pipeline Plugin - DescriptorImpl checkbox

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-2, build-pipeline-plugin, build-pipeline

Jenkins: **2.46.3** or greater

Build Pipeline Plugin: **1.5.4**

[image]

**What's the benefit of selecting this checkbox in a Pipeline View's configuration page**?

Tried checking and unchecking it, but it doesn't reflect any changes to the pipeline job view page. Some info is here: http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/build-pipeline-plugin/au/com/centrumsystems/hudson/plugin/buildpipeline/trigger/BuildPipelineTrigger.DescriptorImpl.html